# Stuck trying to get the NSString from a UILabel in one Viewcontroller to place in a UITextView of another Viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, uitextview

I have an app with two viewcontrollers and I want to show the text from a UILabel in VC1 in a UITextView inside of VC2.

I have been able to access the UILabel from VC1 in the viewDidLoad of VC2 but the actual text does not appear.

In VC2 I created a VC1 object and can access VC1. Here is the VC2 viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.textView.text = vc1Controller.label.text;
}
```

But when I run the app and the VC2 appears, nothing appears in the UITextView. I do have it wired and can show text by doing an NSLog(@”Yes”); for example in the above method.

When I do an NSLog(@”%@”, vc1Controller.label.text); I get NULL in the output.

Do I need to create a custom getter? Any advice appreciated. I’m relatively new to all programming.

Comment: Does "[vc1Controller self.label.text]" work?

Comment: Where and how did you create VC1? How did you create the label?

Comment: I changed the above, I posted incorrectly my current code. Inside of VC2.m I create an object of VC1. The label is created in VC1 depending on the users input. label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString: user input]; But once created I am trying to show the text in a new VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you pass a NSString from views:

First View:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel *firstLbl;
NSString *firstString;
}

-(IBAction)labelTouched:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

firstString = @"I'm the first labels text";
firstLbl.text = firstString;

}


-(IBAction)labelTouched:(id)sender{

ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
view2.selectedFirstLabelString = firstString;
[self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];
[view2 release];
}
```

SecondView:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel *secondLbl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *selectedFirstLabelString;

-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end



@implementation ViewController2
@synthesize selectedFirstLabelString;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

secondLbl.text = selectedFirstLabelString;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did try this and the vc1Controller.textString is (null). In VC1 I do a NSLog and the textString outputs correctly but in VC2 it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using a TabBarController for the separate views or are you passing views in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: Neither. My project started as a single view app and I added a new UIViewController. When the user touches the label in VC 1, it triggers an action sheet, with clearing the label as the destructive option or "View" to see the contents of the label. If they choose "View" I want to add a subview (VC2) to show the full contents of label. I have this setup now with the "View" option just changing the alpha of a UIView in VC1 but I was trying to add a new subview in a separate controller. I have this 2nd version working, except that I am not able to access the label.text in the new view controller.

Comment: Ok that should be fairly simple. I have created a test and it is working. To Pass information to a "detailed view" you must retain that object from a the detailed view and pass it when you init from the first view. To pass information back "second/first" you must create a delegate in the second view and grab the information in the first view from the delegate. Hope this helps out.

Comment: This helps a ton. I see that this creates programmatically a new UITextView and doesn't open the nib I created with a UITextView. Now I need to figure out how to amend this new view created or have my nib open instead. If you feel like helping more or I will continue to study / test. I will be marking this I just don't want to close yet.

Comment: I see how to initialize my nib but for some reason I still get a (null) output for "selectedFirstLabelString" in VC2. With time I will get this.

Comment: Got it. I can't thank you enough! Great community here to help.

Comment: Make sure when Presenting that view you call out View2.SelectedFirstlabelString = firstString; Alternatively you can just create a hierarchy of UIViews in your first UIViewController. To do so just create UIView *viewInsideView1 UILabel *detailedLabel in view 1 and just animate the view in and out without the need of passing a string or view controller.

Comment: I did have a hierarchy of UIViews in VC1 and animated the UITextView.alpha from 0 to 1 to open along with a nav bar and close button and 1 to 0 to close but creating the new VC and passing the string seemed to me to be a better way of doing it. Maybe I'm wrong and my first way was fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
self.textView.text = [vc1Controller self.label.text];
```

You are using the `self` keyword in `[vc1Controller self.label.text]`, but that is going to reference a nonexistent UILabel in the current view controller (View Controller 2). Make the label in vc1Controller a property, and then use:

```
vc1Controller.label.text;
```

to access its text value.

Comment: I changed my original post to match what you suggested. I actually did try this. I don't receive any compile errors but I don't access the text value for some reason. I get a NULL output.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a VC1 object in VC2, you are obviously not referring to the VC1 that pushed VC2.

Your vc2 is trying to read a label value from the newly created vc1, while you actually want to read the value from the VC1 that pushed VC2.

There are a few ways you can get your code working:

1) accessing the parentViewController (if you are presenting vc2 as modal)

In VC2, you can refer to your parent controller:

VC1* vc = (VC1 *)self.parentViewController;
VC2.textView.text = vc.label.text;

2) Accessing the vc1 from the navigationcontroller stack:
[How to access the stack in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498017/how-to-acess-the-stack-in-uinavigationcontroller) This post has it all

3) Use Delegate pattern.
[Custom delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675711/custom-delegate) This one has it all!

Hope you find this useful.