# How to know which views (or view controllers) are on stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

As far as I know, when the app is launched the first view controller gets loaded and his view gets presented. Then you navigate to the next view controller and the previous view controller remains on stack. Therefore if you want to go back you have to dismiss the current view controller, so that the current VC gets cleared out of stack.

I'd like to check my views on stack since my storyboard is getting a little more complex and want to make sure I'm doing everything right. I'm looking for a solution for views that are presented modally as well as views that are presented inside a navigation controller.

How to check which view controllers are on stack?

I've made a longer intro since I'm not sure if I've used the appropriate terminology, I'm willing to correct mistakes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498017/how-to-access-the-stack-in-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the topmost (or any) UIViewController and that you are using UINavigationController (the one with the navigation bar on top of the screen) then

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

gives you an array of all view controllers on stack.

If you present modally then you would need to iterate over `self.presentingViewController` and its `presentingViewController` and so forth until presentingViewController is `null` and create the array yourelf.

However, don't mess up with the stack of view controllers! You are most probalby on the wrong track when you think of this as solution for your problem. Better re-visit your problem and your app's navigation architecture.

Comment: I gladly accept any downvote when you are just kind enough of leaving a comment with some reasoning. I might even agree and amend my answer or delete it.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? This is the correct answer. The only thing that I disagree with is "don't ever modify the navigation stack"; it's perfectly safe to do (and in some cases, necessary) as long as there are no push/pop animations currently in progress

Comment: Pretty sure Hermann has seen quite a few downvotes on correct answers till now. You have my upvote to make up for it.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant, you are right. By saying "don't mess up ..." (not "don't ever modify" I just wanted to warn that somebody can eaisly get messed up when modifying it just because your storyboard seems to become to complex. It is an open API or a read/write property and therefore may well be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the property viewControllers at your UINavigationControllers. The viewController is an array of View Controllers - you can access each ones of these elements.

```
 UIViewController *viewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[i];
```